# jquery ajax data not showing in div tag

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

So I'll start off by saying that I probably am missing something obvious but I really can't figure this out.
I have a filter that gets passed to ajax that puts data into a `div` container that I just created. When I click the filter it grabs the data and will put it into an `alert` but not into the `div` tag I created

ajax call:

```
$('.sponsorFilter').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

        var action = 'sponsorsfilter';

        $.ajax({
            url:    "Sponsors/action.sponsors.php",
            type:   "POST",
            data:{ action:action, id:id },
            success: function(data){
            alert(data);
                $('.sponsorOutput').html(data);
            },
            error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });

});
```

html:

```
<div id="options" class="clearfix">
                  <ul id="filters" class="pagination option-set clearfix" data-option-key="filter">
                    <li><a class="sponsorFilter" href="#filter" data-option-value="*" class="selected">Show all</a></li>
                    <li><a class="sponsorFilter" href="#filter" data-id="Saddlery" data-option-value=".Saddlery">Saddlery</a></li>
                    <li><a class="sponsorFilter" href="#filter" data-id="Animals" data-option-value=".Animals ">Animals and Pets</a></li>
                    <li><a class="sponsorFilter" href="#filter" data-id="Automotive" data-option-value=".Automotive">Automotive</a></li>
                    <li><a class="sponsorFilter" href="#filter" data-id="Beauty" data-option-value=".Beauty">Beauty</a></li>
                    <li><a class="sponsorFilter" href="#filter" data-id="Services" data-option-value=".Services">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a class="sponsorFilter" href="#filter" data-id="Sports" data-option-value=".Sports">sports</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </div><!-- #options -->
              <div class="containerExtra">
              <div id="container" class="clearfix">
               <div class="sponsorOutput">

               <?php
                            $getSponsors = getSponsors($page);
                            while($row = $getSponsors->fetch()){
                        ?>


                        <div class="element transition <?php echo $row['FilterName']; ?>" data-category="transition">
                                        <a href="<?php echo $row['SponsorWeb']; ?>" class="thumb"><figure class="img-polaroid"><img src="<?php echo $row['SponsorLogo']; ?>" alt="" height="200" width="200"></figure></a><span class="description"><?php echo $row['SponsorName']; ?></span>

                                    </div>
                        <?php } ?>

                      </div>
                        <?php
                            if(isset ($_SESSION['userid']))
                            {

                            ?>      
                            <!-- <form action='sponsor.php' method='post' id='sponsors-form'> -->

                            <?php echo $row['SponsorPhone']; ?><br>
                            <?php echo $row['SponsorComments']; ?><br>
                            <input class='myButton' onClick="location.href='sponsors.php?SponsorID=<?php echo $row['SponsorID']; ?>'"  type='submit' name='btnDelete' value='Delete'>   
                            <input class='myButton' onClick="location.href='Sponsors/SponsorEdit.php?SponsorID=<?php echo $row['SponsorID']; ?>'"  type='submit' name='btnDelete' value='Edit'> 

    <!-- </form> -->
                            <?php
                            }

                            ?>

    </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: yeah at the beginning of the js page I call it. I know the call works because the alert has all of the correct data in it

Comment: Instead of accessing by class name we should access div by its id. So in my opinion provide id to the div and then access the div by $('#id'). html... since you are accessing by class so it returns array. In this case you have to specify which element of the array I.e. $('.spon...') [0].html...

Comment: that seemed to work - thank you